# Dynamic drop down list content/behavior using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a use case in our UI, where I need to perform some hacky JQuery operations to dynamically populate a drop down box. Here is the scenario:

I have the following two select boxes and their options:

```
<span class="select levelSelect expandable-list  replacement select-styled-list tracked focus select-clone tracking open" tabindex="-1" style="width: 157px; position: absolute; top: 566.733px; left: 338px;">
   <select id="select1" name="select1" class="validate[required] withClearFunctions" tabindex="-1">
      <option selected="" value="">Select one...</option>
      <option value="option1">option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">option 2</option>
   </select>
   <span class="select-value">Select one...</span>
</span>

<span class="select levelSelect expandable-list  replacement select-styled-list" tabindex="0">
   <select id="select2" name="select2" class="validate[required] withClearFunctions" tabindex="-1">
      <option selected="" value="">Select one...</option>
      <option value="optionA">option A</option>
      <option value="optionB">option B</option>
   </select>
   <span class="select-value">Select one...</span>
 </span>
```

Any change/selection for select1, invokes a change handler function, which needs to perform the following actions for select2:

- If select1 == option1, Add an option for "N/A" (don't want this option to be seen), set "N/A" as the value
- Otherwise, take out "N/A" if option 1 was previously selected, select ""
- You should be able to repeatedly change select1 and get the same behavior

This is what I have tried:

```
if (select1 == "option1") {

   // Add and select N/A 
   $("#select2").append('<option value="N/A">N/A</option>')
   $("#select2").val('N/A');
}
else {
   // Remove N/A option and select nothing
   $("#select2").val('');
   $("#select2" + " option[value='N/A']").remove();
}
```

Regardless of what is selected on select1, the selection/options for select2 do not change. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("#select2 + "[value='N/A']").remove();` - how you are handling quotes here, should result in a syntax error.

Comment: I updated the script example above. I had to obfuscate it a bit due to work policy, and in doing so I left out a handful of quotes.  I am not having any issues building, or receiving any syntax errors, just not getting the "N/A" <-> "" behavior working.

Comment: `$("#select2" + "[value='N/A']")` would select an element with that ID and that value. This is missing a space in between, if this is supposed to select _descendants_ of that ID, having that value. Also, you _created_ the option element without a specific value set, not sure if the attribute selector will work then.

Comment: Good catch on the space. I updated the code example above, and my own code. I am still seeing the same behavior however. Essentially, my change handler script is called (the show and hides in there happen), but options/selections for select2 are simply never changed. It's like I am missing a refresh or trigger.

Comment: Had a not properly closed option element in there as well, but that should not prevent it from working. This here does what it should, right? https://jsfiddle.net/4a39g0L7/

Comment: Yeah that looks spot-on.

Comment: So further down the rabbit hole, I can strip everything else out of my function but my first append statement "$("#select2").append('<option value="N/A">N/A</option>')", add a console.log entry, and the log shows up and the append does not happen. I can copy that exact append statement, dump it in the Firefox debug console, execute it, and it works. That being said the select stuff is only pseudo-happening in the Firefox debugger, so more weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was missing after each select box action:

```html
.trigger('update-select-list').trigger('change');
```